# Can i expose multiple docker containers behind nat to be accessible from the web

Tags: linux, docker

I have a single static ip and want to know if it is possible to run several containers (lets say with ssh and apache) and let them be accessible from outside my local network by using my public ip. I tried it by using bind9 but dont think that works because i only have 1 ip address.

Some kind of router which connects based on a hostname or something for example?

I ended up using kubernetes with a clusterIP and nodePort service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by having a reverse proxy like nginx in front of your containers.

Nginx will then receive all the requests and route them to the correct container, based on the hostname.

More info here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Comment: Is it possible to proxy all requests regardless of protocol or port so that they act like real virtual private servers so that every team member can access his vps from anywhere on every protocol?

Comment: If you want to route all traffic then you'd need to do it by port number. I.e. ssh on container1 could be port 22, ssh on container 2 could be port 23 etc. And then you might as well just map the container ports to host ports using Docker. You can only share a port if you can route based on the content of the traffic, i.e. hostname in HTTP.

Comment: Thats what i do right now so i think i am stuck on that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `docker -p` parameter can map multiple different SSH or Apache ports

Comment: I dont want to map ports to my host network, i want something like an ipvlan but routable throu my nat by using theyr hostnames instead of ip or something like that. So that for e.g domain.com is my domain and calling `ssh host1.domain.com` or `ssh host2.domain.com` would establish a ssh connection to the corresponding container but **from outside my home network**